# How do I use FASM with GDB?

Tags: gdb, fasm

Given I have a basic `.asm` file and I compile it with `fasm`, what is the best practice for using gdb to debug it with the symbols and whatever else may be a best practice?

Comment: welp, we both have the same problem...

Comment: Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exd_p4K675o